# C++ XQuery engine - zorba or XQilla or another

Tags: c++, linux, xquery, zorba

I have been using zorba for a little while and it seems to generally work. But it seems to leak memory here and there and I am having to look at other options.

Has anyone had luck with any other XQuery engines in linux environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new zorba 1.4 pretty OK! So I am putting this to bed till I get around to trying XQilla.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to give http://www.basex.org a try. Though it is not C++ it is still compact, fast and very complete :-)

Comment: Does your project require C++ or is it driven by the common prejudices against java ;-)? Just asking out of interest, I'm pretty sure you'd get along well.

Comment: To be really honest, I am not very keen to use a sledge hammer to break a peanut. Java is good and it has its place. In this case, I have XML documents POSTed to me which has to be transformed to data objects that need further processing. All this need to be as light as possible. No fancy extra horse powers to waste.